# Manipulate Database from Drupal

Tags: database, drupal-7, datamodule

I'm new to Drupal 7. Right now I'm trying to use D7 to build an interface that allows me to directly manipulate the tables in the database.
I have installed a couple modules such as Data, Migrate, Feeds, and etc. I managed to create a view to display the table that I created using Data Module, but I need to add and update the rows from the interface. 
Furthermore, is it possible to set up relational tables so that I can update or delete related rows at the same time using Drupal?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the data module that is quite easy because it comes with the "Data Entity" submodule that creates an entity form for you. This allows you to update data table rows. It should add an edit button at the end of your data view for the table.

Using some basic custom code you can always create a form to add/update data to the table as well. For form creation please have a look at:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/group/form_api/7

Comment: I ended up creating a new content type to match up with my table I imported from a csv file using feeds importer. And used Views to display the contents. Still thanks for the help.